# Why there are random line breaks in emails sent through drupal?

Tags: 7, emails

I noticed drupal includes line breaks in emails it outputs.

For example in `admin/config/people/accounts` we can customize message users receive when they signup and/or when they forget their passwords etc..

The thing is, when the emails are sent to the users, they contain line breaks that seem to be completely random and arbitrary.

I first thought the problem came from the webmail provider, so i tried with different services (gmail, hotmail, yahoo etc.. )

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's drupal's mail processor that inserts all these line breaks.
I fixed the issue by installing MimeMail (and MailSystem).
It allows the use of html to format all outgoing emails.

I hope this will be helpful to somebody out there.